# No. of likes+comments on posts of user by his/her friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to find a best friend among all my friends. A best friend is one who have liked or commented most on your posts. So, I need to find no of comments + like on my all posts by my friends and then mind the maxium of them to get best friend.

Can someone provide a fql query or graph api ?